# Use CSS variables in Stylus iterations

Tags: css, stylus, css-variables

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

For example, in a CSS preprocessor like stylus:

```
// want to use this css variable
:root {
  --i-menu-count: 5
}

$item-count = 5
for $i in (1..$item-count) {
  .menu:nth-child({$i}) .menu-title {
    transform: rotate(-180deg / ($item-count - 1) * ($i - 1))
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use CSS variables `--i-menu-count` to replace `$item-count` in the iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but `-` is operator if your var name start with `--` the stylus parser throw error

I suggest you to declare your count in stylus

like

```
item-count = 5

for i in (1..item-count)
    .menu:nth-child({i}) .menu-title {
       transform: rotate(-180deg / (item-count - 1) * (i - 1))
    }
```

Comment: I mean that I want to change the stylus's variable to css variable, is that possible!?

Comment: No you can't because you can't name your stylus variable with operator and --var-name contain "-" and is operator so you cant